# Use python for loop to get txt values and calculate the sum of values

Tags: python, for-loop, text, average, typeerror

my program is after read the txt file, it could display the average values.
First it is the apart of text file format, it has more lines here.

```
Timestamp                 CounterSamples                                       

---------                 --------------                                       

3/15/2017 2:01:44 PM      \\ins1617group15s\processor(_total)\% processor time 

                          :                                                    

                          1.38923436719549                                     





3/15/2017 2:01:46 PM      \\ins1617group15s\processor(_total)\% processor time 

                          :                                                    

                          0.318628588938252                                    





3/15/2017 2:01:48 PM      \\ins1617group15s\processor(_total)\% processor time 

                          :                                                    

                          0.319297841379995
```

And it is my code to get the values first:

```
infile = open(cpu_txtfile, 'r')
stuff = infile.readlines()
for i in range(0, 500, 5):
    values = float(stuff[i+5])
```

It is success to callback each line of values and format like this:

```
1.3892343672
0.318628588938
0.31929784138
1.26366523362
1.42940775782
0.112588096327
1.24699147593
0.300931193494
1.8688601978
0.2750450877
0.848266656567
1.6158389729
0.0820226675922
0.0
1.45128654463
2.03801885286
```

I have another for loop to calculate

```
 for j in range(0, 99):
            sum_values = values[j+1]
            avg_values = sum_values / 100
            print avg_values
```

It has the error code

```
    line 139, in cpu_baselineValues
    sum_values = values[j+1]
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

It seems that can not call the `values` of each line. Is that the problem of values data types?

Answer (score 1):

More pythonic version of @klutt code:

```
values = [float(stuff[i*5+5] for i in range(0, 100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just reassigning the value of the float variable values. You need to use an array instead.

Turn this

```
for i in range(0, 500, 5):
    values = float(stuff[i+5])
```

into something like this

```
values=zeros(500)
for i in range(0, 100):
    values[i] = float(stuff[i*5+5])
```

Note that this does not necessarily work flawlessly with just copy-pasting. I have not checked the numbers in detail, but it shows the basic principle.

Comment: Would you like to explain to the OP how are you to do that?

Comment: Thanks for help first, after reference your answer, I have change my code to this:`for i in range(0, 500, 5):
        values = []
        values[i] = float(stuff[i+5])`But it has a error there: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` Is that the code problem or the size of list?